# why am i not getting the data of record and just lable in visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Bolow is my visulforce Page and apex page i am expecting output as a single record in 2 column and has next and previous button to next and previous record. but just showing lables not values...

```
public with sharing class MyController 
{
    public list<Patient__c> objectList = new List<Patient__c>();
    public list<Patient__c> currentObject {get; set;}
    public integer i;
    public MyController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {myAction();}
    
    public string selectedValue {get; set;}
    public boolean myBoolean {get; set;}    
    
    public void myAction()
    {
        if ( selectedValue == 'List View') { myBoolean = True; }
        else { myBoolean = False ;}
    } 
    
    public Patient__c getCurrentObject()
    {
    return currentObject[i];
    }
    
    public void goToPrevious(){
    if (i>0){i--;}
    }
    
    public void goToNext() {
        if (i < currentObject.size() - 1) {
            i++;
        }
    }    
   /* public void goToRecord (Id recordId) {
        for (Integer i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++) {
            if (objectList[i].Id == recordId) {
                i = i;
                break; 
            } 
        }
    } */
}
```

Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Patient__c" extensions="MyController" recordSetVar="Patients">
<apex:pageBlock title="Patient Records...!!!">
    <apex:form >
    <div align='center' style=' color:blue;font-size:10px '>
            Your selection is {!selectedValue}
    </div>
    <apex:selectList label="View Type"  value="{!selectedValue}" size="1">
            <apex:selectOption itemvalue="Standared View" itemLabel="Standared View"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemvalue="List View" itemLabel="List View"/>   
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!myAction}" >                 
        </apex:actionSupport>
    </apex:selectList>
    </apex:form>
<apex:pageBlock rendered="{!myBoolean}"> 
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Patients}" var="Pa" >
    <apex:column value="{!Pa.Name}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!Pa.Contact_Number__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!Pa.Email__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!Pa.Age__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlock title="Standared View" rendered="{!!myBoolean}"> 
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
        <apex:outputField value="{!Patient__c.Name}"/>    
        <apex:outputField value="{!Patient__c.Age__c}"/>            
        <apex:outputField value="{!Patient__c.Email__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:form >
            <apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!goToPrevious}" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!goToNext}"/>           
    </apex:form> 
</apex:pageBlock>    
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason you are not seeing the values is because **you have not queried them in your constructor in order to show then**.

here is more simplified version that works.

**Please change variable name accordingly :-
In my case i have used Student__c Object for testing**

Vf Page:

```
<apex:page controller="MyController">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Patient Records...!!!">
        <apex:form>
            <div align='center' style='color:blue;font-size:10px'>
                Your selection is {!selectedValue}
            </div>
             <apex:selectList value="{!selectedValue}" size="1">
            <apex:selectOption itemvalue="Standared View" itemLabel="Standared View"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemvalue="List View" itemLabel="List View"/>   
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!myAction}" >                 
        </apex:actionSupport>
    </apex:selectList>
        </apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!myBoolean}">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!stu}" var="Pa">
                <apex:column value="{!Pa.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!Pa.City__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!Pa.Class__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!Pa.State__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock title="Standard View" >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
                <apex:outputField value="{!stu.Name}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!stu.City__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!stu.Class__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:form>
                <apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!goToPrevious}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!goToNext}"/>
            </apex:form>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class MyController {
    public List<Student__c> objectList { get; set; }
    public List<Student__c> currentObject { get; set; }
    public Integer i { get; set; }
    public String selectedValue { get; set; }
    public Boolean myBoolean { get; set; }
    Public Student__c stu {get;set;}

    public MyController() {
        i=0
        myAction();
      
        // Query the Students list and populate the objectList 
        objectList = new List<Student__c>([SELECT Name, City__c, Class__c, State__c FROM Student__c where city__c!=null]);
        stu=objectList[i];
    }

    public void myAction() {
        if (selectedValue == 'List View') {
            myBoolean = true;
        } else {
            myBoolean = false;
        }
    }

    public Student__c getCurrentObject() {
      
        return objectList[i];
    }

    public void goToPrevious() {
        if (i > 0) {
            i--;
        }
        stu=objectList[i];
    }

    public void goToNext() {
        System.debug('currentObject'+objectList.size()+objectList);
        if (i < objectList.size() - 1) {
            i++;
        }
        stu=objectList[i];
    }
}
```